# does android's MediaPlayer run in a thread by default?

Tags: android, android-studio

Suppose I've created two Buttons in the `activity_main.xml` like:

```
...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    ...
    android:onClick="playMusic1"
    android:text="music1.mp3"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    ...
    android:onClick="playMusic2"
    android:text="music2.mp3"
/>
...
```

which play `music1.mp3` and `music2.mp3` respectively using something like this:

```
...
public void playMusic1(View view)throws IOException {
        Button passed_btn = (Button)view;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(passed_btn.getText().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    }
...   





...
public void playMusic2(View view)throws IOException {
        Button passed_btn = (Button)view;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(passed_btn.getText().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    }
...
```

When I launch the application, I can play both the songs simultaneously, I think it's because `MediaPlayer` runs in a thread separate from the main thread, but neither [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) nor in [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram) is anything mentioned about `MediaPlayer` being in a thread. It does mention to trigger some states asynchronously  but that's about it.(Though it may be I could have missed it). And if it does run in a thread, what is the number of media that we can play simultaneously?

Comment: MediaPlayer is deprecated, I suggest use exoplayer instead.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule, it's deprecated? Like the whole class? The docs don't say so though, how do you know it is deprecated?

Comment: Not the hole class but most of the answer you will find here will contains deprecated methods. They overwritten methods most of the times. I prefer `ExoPlayer` so just suggesting you.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule , the problem with exoplayer is that it's opensource, doesn't that imply your project's gonna be opensource too....

Comment: Exoplayer allows free for Commercial use, Modification, Distribution, Patent use, Private use except Trademark use, Liability, Warranty. What else do you need?

Comment: @KaushikBurkule , it says in https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/LICENSE that you need to include the license and copyright notice, does that mean we should include a copy in our apk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202455/discussion-between-kaushik-burkule-and-juztcode).

Answer (score 1):

It does run in `Thread`. But it's not something like we used to think about. When you start playing media file - in the native implementation (handled by native media libs) creates new `Thread`s with bytes from the sound source. Later this source consumed by native `MediaService` into single audio output and navigates to the [HAL](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hal).

Comment: What is HAL that you mention? and where is this bit of information given, can you perhaps provide a link if it's somewhere?

Comment: is it true that the whole MediaPlayer class is deprecated?

Comment: @juztcode Of course no. maybe it's rewritten hounder times, but it's root object for media handling. However Android devs prefer `ExoPlayer` for media work. Because Google `ExoPlayer` just extension for `MediaPlayer` which cover some low level work.

Comment: I'm still confused about some of these licensing things, but, isn't using ExoPlayer gonna make your whole project opensource?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you.

Comment: I mean if say, the opensource project is GPL licensed then acc to GPL we'd have to opensource our app/software, right?

Comment: @juztcode I'm not sure about all this licensing stuff, but you don't need to make your project open source with using `ExoPlayer`. We were using it without problem and internal customization for thousands of users.

Comment: it turns out it is true, like literally, cause exoplayer seems to be using the apache license: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/LICENSE not the GPL. :-)

Comment: in your software that you mentioned earlier, did you keep a copy of the apache app license included with the apk or something like that? I don't know if the conditions in the git page that I linked above are saying that